# Google Drive API v3 загружает пустой файл (php)

Tags: php, google-drive

Загружаю pdf файл при выполнение php файла.
Загружается пустой файл и не могу понять в чем проблема, по url файл уже лежит.

```
require_once './google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Drive;

function uploadBasic()
{
    try {
        $client = new Client();
        //$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->setAuthConfig('./google-api-php-client/1710-6c50418be6b2.json');
        $client->addScope(Drive::DRIVE);
        $driveService = new Drive($client);
        
        $fileMetadata = new Drive\DriveFile(array(
                'parents' => ['225qhcKKyf8Ot0IhrRxRtqgHNTxLV1LiyI'],
                'name' => 'test.pdf',
                'mimeType' => 'application/pdf'));
        
        $mimeType=mime_content_type($fileMetadata);
        $content = file_get_contents('https://example.com/test.pdf');
        $file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array([
                    'data' => $content,
                    'mimeType' => 'application/pdf',
                    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
                    'fields' => 'id']));
        printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
        return $file->id;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Error Message: ".$e;
    }   
}

uploadBasic();
```

Comment: Сохраните файл на локальный диск и проверьте на соответствие. Скорее всего у вас проблема с чтением сертификата через file_get_contents.

Comment: на соответствие чего ? я с пк закидую на сервер файл и его хочу отправить на гугл драйв. запускаю test.php который должен закинуть test.pdf на гугл драйв. а он только создает файл и он пустой. и на етом все..

Comment: то что получили через file_get_contents на сервере сохраните и  проверьте чего он там скачал. Вообще, если вы загружаете файл на тот сервер, где скрипт, то почему урл указыаваете, а не локальный путь? В случае ошибки функция возвращает false, а ошибка может возникать в случае ошибки проверки сертификата ссл. Если вернулся false, то и файл на диске пустой получите. По крайней мере следует проверить `$content !== false`. Но опять таки, если файл локально, то локально и читайте его

Comment: @teran файл находиться на том же сервере где и выполняется файл, указываю весь путь что бы не ошибиться при с вложенностью папок. это может как-то повлиять на file_get_contents  ?типа указываю file_get_contents (./xxxx.pdf) или file_get_contents(https://site.com/xxxx.pdf)?

Comment: @teran вообщем в $content есть данные картинки попробовал через абсолютный путь, картину не поменяло...